# Insert a figure such that there is text to the right of it

Tags: graphics, floats

Right now I'm using the following at the top of my document:

```
\begin{flushright}
\textbf{\large My name}
\vspace{3pt}
\hrule
\vspace{3pt}
Street 1a\\
Postal code + city\\
Phone number\\
Email@test.com
\end{flushright}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\includegraphics{picture.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

This displays the jpg left aligned but below the line containing my email address. Is there a way to move the picture "up" so that its top is below the `\hrule`, exactly as the line containing the street?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}
\textbf{\large My name}
\vspace{3pt}
\hrule
\vspace{3pt}
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}%adjust as needed
   [0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{tiger}}
\hfill Street 1a\\    Postal code + city\\    Phone number\\    Email@test.com
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm, the environment `flushright` (and also `flushleft`) is a `list` environment who has only one item, which means it will add extra vertical space at the top and bottom of the environment, and may cause some other problems. Maybe we should always use `\raggedleft` rather than the environment `flushright`?

Comment: @Ch'enMeng It very depends on what is the OP exactly after. Without a MWE, it's hard to say. But clearly he uses this environment himself.

Comment: @tohecz: OK, I got that.